# jQuery search for child element, but not with certain div

Tags: jquery

I want to stop searching for a specific child element after another element is encountered.

```
$("parent").find("children").dontSearchWithin("nothere");
```

Basically I want to select all children elements, but not children elements that are within a specific div.

Heres an example http://codepen.io/Jarolin/pen/hCqAa

I dont want to select the span that are within the "not-here" element.

```
<div id="parent">
  <span>FIND ME</span>
  <span>FIND ME</span>
  <span>FIND ME</span>
  <span>FIND ME</span>

 <div id="not-here">
   <span>IGNORE</span>
   <span>IGNORE</span>
   <span>IGNORE</span>
 </div>
```

Also this could have more child elements. and the span wont necessarily be direct children of the parent. The can be children of children of child elements of the parent element. If that makes sence

Comment: Your HTML is missing a closing div tag.

Comment: Its not the HTML in my actual project. Just a simple mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `not()` to filter the selection:

```js
var spans = $('#parent').find('span').not('#not-here span');

spans.css('color', '#f90');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
  <span>FIND ME</span>
  <span>FIND ME</span>
  <span>FIND ME</span>
  <span>FIND ME</span>

  <div id="not-here">
    <span>IGNORE</span>
    <span>IGNORE</span>
    <span>IGNORE</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Referencees:

- [`not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/).